# Horizontal scrolling jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll

I'm having trouble scrolling horizontally with jquery. I'm using anchors to absolute positioned divs. to achieve the scroll. the problem is , the scroll position(left offset) is not consistent when viewed in different resolutions.

here's a link to my project : http://www.topazbranch.com/FB_others/preview2/Callme2.html

any suggestions ? I was having no problem when the whole page was positioned left. however , after I've positioned it in the middle of the page. I've been having this problem.

Comment: Got it fixed by myself haha check same link http://www.topazbranch.com/FB_others/preview2/Callme2.html